Maximum of Hadamard product of matrix with Frobenius norm of 1
I met this problem on entrance exam to ML school and I couldn't solve it.
Let $A\in M_{n\times r}(\mathbb{R}), B\in M_{m\times r}(\mathbb{R}), C\in M_{n\times m}$.
Let $A^TA=I_n$, $B^TB=I_m$.
Find $X\in M_{n\times m}(\mathbb{R})$, s.t. $Im(X) \subset Im(A)$, $Im(X^T) \subset Im(B)$, $\sum_{i, j}x_{i, j}^2$ = 1
for each $\sum_{i, j}x_{i, j}c_{i, j}$ = 1 is maximal.
What I managed to do:
columns of $A$ form orthonormal system of vectors, $\forall v \in Im(A)$ $AA^Tv=v$. Similarly, $\forall v \in Im(B)$ $BB^Tv=v$.
So each matrix $X$ can be written as a solution of the following system:
$(AA^T-I_n)X=0$
$(BB^T-I_m)X^T=0$
It's easy to see that each matrix of form $AYB$ is a solution for any $Y$. It seems that all solutions can be written in this form. However, I don't know how to prove it.
Assuming it's true, we need to find $Y$ s.t. $||AYB||_F = 1$ and $AYB \odot C$ is maximal. I tried to calculate derivatives, but unsuccessful.
Any help would be appreciated.

Out of curiosity, which ML school is this?

We are going to use a method of Lagrange multipliers.
We also note
$$(AA^T-I_n)^T = AA^T-I_n$$
$$(AA^T-I_n)^2 = -(AA^T-I_n)$$
$$(AA^T-I_n)AA^T = 0$$
and similarly for $B$.
The Lagrangian function can be written as
$$\mathcal{L} = \operatorname{tr} (C^T X) + \lambda (\operatorname{tr}(X^TX) - 1) + \operatorname{tr} (\Lambda_1^T (AA^T - I_n)X) + \operatorname{tr}((BB^T - I_m)X^T \Lambda_2)$$
where we've used the fact that for any matrices $G$ and $H$ we have $\sum_{ij} G_{ij} H_{ij} = \operatorname{tr} (G^T B)$. Here $\lambda$ is a scalar but $\Lambda_1$ and $\Lambda_2$ are matrices of Lagrange multipliers. The stationary point of this Lagrange function will correspond to the extremum of $\operatorname{tr} (C^T X)$ given the conditions $\operatorname{tr}(X^TX) = 1$, $(AA^T - I_n)X = 0$ and $(BB^T - I_m)X^T = 0$.
To find the stationary point we take matrix partial derivatives:
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial X} = C + 2\lambda X + (AA^T-I_n) \Lambda_1 + \Lambda_2 (BB^T-I_m) = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \Lambda_1} = (AA^T-I_n)X = 0, \quad \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \Lambda_2} = X(BB^T - I_m) = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \lambda} = \operatorname{tr}(X^TX) - 1 = 0$$
From the first condition we have
$$X = -\frac{1}{2\lambda} (C + (AA^T-I_n) \Lambda_1 + \Lambda_2 (BB^T-I_m))$$
If we multiply this expression from the left by $(AA^T-I_n)$ and from the right by $(BB^T-I_m)$, following the next two conditions, we obtain a system of equations:
$$(AA^T-I_n)C - (AA^T-I_n)\Lambda_1 + (AA^T-I_n)\Lambda_2 (BB^T-I_m) = 0$$
$$C(BB^T-I_m) + (AA^T-I_n)\Lambda_1(BB^T-I_m) - \Lambda_2(BB^T-I_m) = 0$$
We can simplify it separating $\Lambda_1$ and $\Lambda_2$ by multiplying the second equation by $(AA^T-I_n)$ from the left and taking the sum and by multiplying the first equation by $(BB^T-I_m)$ from the right and taking the sum:
$$(AA^T-I_n)CBB^T = (AA^T-I_n)\Lambda_1 BB^T$$
$$AA^TC(BB^T - I_m) = AA^T\Lambda_2(BB^T - I_m)$$
Multiplying the expression for $X$ by $AA^T$ from the left and by $BB^T$ from the right and using the last two equations we obtain:
$$AA^TX = -\frac{1}{2\lambda} AA^T C BB^T$$
$$XBB^T = -\frac{1}{2\lambda} AA^T C BB^T$$
We can see that $X = -\frac{1}{2\lambda} AA^T C BB^T$ is the solution with $\Lambda_1 = \frac12 C(BB^T+I_m)$ and $\Lambda_2 = \frac12 (AA^T+I_n)C$. To satisfy the last condition for the stationary point we should take $\lambda = \pm \frac12 ||AA^T C BB^T||_F$.
Then if we take $\lambda$ with a minus sign we have
$$X = \frac{AA^T C BB^T}{||AA^T C BB^T||_F}$$
The norm can be rewritten using the cyclic property of the trace:
$$||AA^T C BB^T||_F^2 = \operatorname{tr} (BB^TC^TAA^TAA^TCBB^T) = \operatorname{tr} (BB^TC^TAA^TCBB^T) = \operatorname{tr} (C^TAA^TCBB^TBB^T) = \operatorname{tr} (C^TAA^TCBB^T)$$
Therefore we have $\operatorname{tr} (C^T X) = ||AA^T C BB^T||_F$. If it is also given that this is $1$, it simply follows:
$$\boxed{X = AA^T C BB^T}$$
We can also prove that $||AA^T C BB^T||_F$ is indeed a (global) maximal value. Consider an increment $X + \Delta X$ where $\Delta X \neq 0$ is not necessary small. It should follow the same conditions as the $X$. Then $$\operatorname{tr} ((X+\Delta X)^T(X+\Delta X)) = \operatorname{tr} (X^T X) + 2\operatorname{tr}(X^T \Delta X) + \operatorname{tr} (\Delta X^T \Delta X) = 1 + 2\operatorname{tr}(X^T \Delta X) + \operatorname{tr} (\Delta X^T \Delta X) = 1$$
$$2\operatorname{tr}(X^T \Delta X) + \operatorname{tr} (\Delta X^T \Delta X) = 0$$
$$2\operatorname{tr}(BB^TC^TAA^T \Delta X) + ||AA^T C BB^T||_F\operatorname{tr} (\Delta X^T \Delta X) = 0$$
Since we have $AA^T \Delta X = \Delta X$ and $\Delta X BB^T = \Delta X$:
$$2\operatorname{tr}(C^T\Delta X) + ||AA^T C BB^T||_F\operatorname{tr} (\Delta X^T \Delta X) = 0$$
On the other hand
$$\operatorname{tr} (C^T(X+\Delta X)) = \operatorname{tr} (C^TX) + \operatorname{tr} (C^T\Delta X) = ||AA^T C BB^T||_F + \operatorname{tr} (C^T\Delta X) = ||AA^T C BB^T||_F \left(1 - \frac12 \operatorname{tr} (\Delta X^T \Delta X)\right)$$
Since for any $X+\Delta X$ we have $\operatorname{tr} (C^T(X+\Delta X))$ smaller than $||AA^T C BB^T||_F$ it proves that it is a maximal value.
Note, that if we somehow guessed this form of $X$, we could avoid using Lagrange multipliers and just prove that it satisfies all the requirements.
